# How to validate SFSpeechRecognizer Speech language identifier using Swift?

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am trying to pass the language code based on it `SFSpeechRecognizer` changing language for `speech to text`. Here, I can able to use only apple provided `63 languages`. If I pass some other languages I am getting crash because of language unavailability. How to validate and handle it in a proper way using `swift`?

My Code

```
private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-US"))  //1
```

I  followed below tutorial for implementing speech to text

> https://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/

Comment: That line of code crashes? Show the crash log please.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the Locale is supported by `supportedLocales`

```
// Locales which support speech recognition.
// Note that supported does not mean currently available; some locales 
// may require an internet connection, for example.
+ (NSSet<NSLocale *> *)supportedLocales;

let locale = Locale(identifier: "hi-IN")

SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales().contains(locale) // Can check using this
let sr = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale)
sr?.isAvailable // Can check using this

lazy var srf: SFSpeechRecognizer? = {
let locale = Locale(identifier: "hi-IN")
return SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales().contains(locale) ? SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale) : nil
}()
```

Comment: Thanks @Hemant Singh. Btw I can't able to understand your answer. I need to declare SFSpeechRecognizer globally also need to validate language.

Comment: You can use lazy init for the global declaration.

Comment: Can you please provide me some other logic?